# Fonts are too sharp on one PC. Anything I can do with this?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, font-smoothing

**tl;dr**: One of my PCs shows a very sharp fonts with little or no blur even though *Smooth edges of images and text* is checked. I can resolve this situation somehow?

---

I have got two computers:

- Windows 10 1909; Word 2010,
- Windows 10 1803; Word 2013.

Second one shows totally sharp and crispy fonts.

Here you have an example. The same document, the same piece of text and the same font used:

[image]

My the only shoot was *Smooth edges of images and text* option. But that one is checked on both computers:

[image]

Anything else that I may try to resolve this?

Comment: I recall going through some steps in Windows which might've been in display settings to help Windows adjust itself to your screen resolution. Like it'd present various test patterns including text with various degrees of sharpness and ask you to pick the one that looks best out of those. Then it'd tune your display according to your responses. If you haven't already found and tried that I can try to track down where I saw this.

Comment: For text in Word, please also try to go to `File > Options > Advanced > Display `, check the box of **Disable hardware graphics acceleration**.

Comment: At least your right example screenshot appears to be strongly compressed JPEG. This makes it difficult to discern what is due to font rendering and what is due to lossy compression of the screenshot. Can you show us a PNG or uncompressed JPEG? Right now, I would consider both examples far from “totally sharp and crisp”.

Comment: Are you viewing a scanned document?

Comment: Thank you for all enlightening comments here. No, I am not viewing a scanned document, but a Word document as I type it. And, yes, JPEG compression does a lot here, but this is only due to image presentation. The real problem is that on two private PCs I have a blured font and on this single one no blur at all. But, I think that problem is solved with @EmilyHua idea above and with the answer below. Thank you.

Comment: @EmilyHua I won't have access to my office PC until Monday, so I won't be able to confirm that, but from the preliminary check, it clearly seems that you hit the jackpot with your suggestion. So, I strongly recommend changing that comment into answer, so I can accept it and bring you some rep., if you wish.

Comment: @trejder Thank you for your reminder. Have you tried it for a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For text in Word, please also try to go to `File > Options > Advanced > Display` , check the box of **Disable hardware graphics acceleration**.

Comment: This is the exact answer that has resolved my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"Start" -> "cttune", Enter.
Adjust clear type settings to your liking.

If it doesn't help, you may try calibrate display and adjust it via graphics driver, but this capabilities are usually pretty poor.

Comment: Marvelous! I forgot about this app. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Verify if the checkbox in old control panel is ticked (system / advanced / performance / visual effects) - at least it has an effect on my fonts in Firefox.

[image: Win-Pause]

Answer (score 0):

Just found this question:

In Acrobat, go to **Edit**> **Preferences**> **Page Display**:

In **Rendering Box** with **Smooth Text**, choose *For Laptop/LCD Screens* from the dropdown menu.

worked for me